# SQL query to sum different values from the same table for different customers [for android]

Tags: android, sqlite

Can some one please help me with:
I have DB with 5 tables : [DB diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DukRh.jpg) stat_list table is pre-populated with 5 values (Att, pass, TD, inter, pass). And I want create a table in android that will display sum of all the values from table Stat_list for every player. Thanks a lot!

[image: Table example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String sQry = "SELECT * FROM Stat_list;";
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    int count = -1;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        db = SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sQry, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int playerScore = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)) +
                                  Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)) +
                                  Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)) +
                                  Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4))
                 ContentValues playerScores = new ContentValues();

                 playerScores.put(THE_NAME_OF_THE_SCORE_COLUMN, playerScore);
                 try{
                     db.update(NAME_OF_TABLE_WITH_SUMMED_PLAYER_SCORES,playerScores, "PlayerName = " cursor.getString(1), null);
                    }catch(SQLiteException e){}
                 } 
                 while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }           
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d("SQL Error", e.getMessage());
    }
    finally { 
        cursor.close();
        db.close(); 
    }
```

The snippet above pulls the information from the db, sums up the scores and inserts it into another table. You'll have to put int he specific values though, such as the correct column and table names.